# MVP-VM vs MVVM in command binding implementation

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, mvvm, mvp

I have a desktop application and I'd like to use MVVM as a design pattern, it seems to me that the `Command Binding` is not so easy to applicate in [WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/238657/How-to-use-Commands-in-WPF) application.

I read this [article](http://aviadezra.blogspot.com/2009/08/mvp-mvvm-winforms-data-binding.html) that explain how to use `MVP-VM` whithin desktop application. So I need to know:

1. Does `MVP-VM` can replace MVVM especially in `Command Binding` concept?
2. If it is the case, why we still using MVVM for `XAML` applications and `MVP` for winforms? I mean Why we don't migrate to a global solution like `MVP-VM`?

Thanks,

Comment: `we don't migrate to a global solution like MVP-VM?` - because no one is willing to give up modern techniques and paradigms (MVVM) in order to support a deprecated technology like winforms. If that were the case, you could as well ask why don't we use a UI paradigm compatible with D.O.S 1.0 and GW-Basic from 1950...

Comment: BTW, MVVM is not something you can *"right click -> convert to MVVM"* after your application is written. If you didn't use MVVM from the beginning, then you'll have to delete all your code and start all over, which in most cases doesn't make any sense. If you're going to do that (or if you're talking about a new project that's just starting) you could as well simply use modern technology and forget winforms forever.

Comment: @HighCore you are right for winforms, but what do  you think about different XAML applications ( Wpf,silverlight,Appstore, WindowsPhone)? Besides What do u think about the first question?

Comment: @HighCore the issue is not about winforms and/or new technologies, it is about design pattern choice

Comment: `the issue is not about winforms and/or new technologies, it is about design pattern choice` - **Simple answer**: if your project is new, then use WPF and MVVM, forget useless winforms. If your project is already written, then this question doesn't make any sense because whatever answer implies a full rewrite.

Comment: Please re-read my question, I don't ask if I have to choose WPF+MVVM or winforms for my new project. I'm asking about a comparison between MVVM && MVP-VM design pattern in a specific concept ( Command Binding).

Comment: I have never done any MVP-VM, but in MVVM, command bindings, InputBindings, EventToCommand, RoutedCommands, and other WPF features work just fine... what's your question?

Comment: I agree with what @HighCore has been saying. What makes you think in any way that command binding is not easy to apply in WPF? Binding is a first class citizen in WPF, and MVVM is the pattern ideally suited to it, so why would you even consider the older MVP pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with the rest of the comments, I don't see what the issue really is with binding or more specifially command binding - as stated already they are first class citizens in WPF.

This is a not a shameless plug :)

I use the following (MVVM) template when creating new WPF projects for clients, it contains a lot of stuff but it does have an example of a command binding, where the command is defined in a VM called Child2ViewModel and this is bound to a data template.

It doesn't use any third party MVVM frameworks as it is a stripped down implmentation - this mean there are several implementations of the ICommand interface, depending on your needs.

https://github.com/oriches/Simple.Wpf.Template

You will require to access to NuGet to build the code.